# Como poner un icono Fontawesome en un boton de DataTable? - Angular

Tags: datatables, angular, angular5, font-awesome

Estoy utilizado [angular-fontawesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome) y [datatables](http://datatables.net) y deseo crear un boton en la tabla, pero en vez de texto quiero colocar un icono utilizando [fontawesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome). poseo el siguiente codigo:

```
this.dtOptions = {
    //...
    buttons: [
        //...
        {
            extend: 'pdf',
            text: '<fa-icon [icon]="faDownload"></fa-icon>'
        }
    ]           
};
```

Yo se que no me cargara en componente del icono de esta manera, pero hay una forma de hacerlo sin tener que utilizar el css de fontawesome?

Comment: que significa "sin tener que utilizar el css de fontawesome" ?

Comment: @aloMalbarez Como dije en la pregunta, quiero utilizar https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome, con el css, cargo iconos inecesarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 hack, 1 intento que no funciona y 1 custom css

**1. Hack**

capturamos la info del icono y lo renderizamos "a pelo"

`app.component.ts`

```
import { faDownload } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

...

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';
  faDownload = faDownload;
  dtOptions: any = {};

...

  elTexto = `<fa-icon class="ng-fa-icon">
  <svg
    aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="`+this.faDownload.prefix+`" data-icon="`+this.faDownload.iconName+`"
    class="svg-inline--fa fa-`+this.faDownload.iconName+`" role="img"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    viewBox="0 0 `+this.faDownload.icon[0]+` `+this.faDownload.icon[1]+`">
    <path fill="currentColor" d="`+this.faDownload.icon[4]+`"></path></svg></fa-icon> Download
  `;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 20,
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      // Configure the buttons
      buttons: [
        'print',
        'excel',
        {
          text: this.elTexto,
          key: '1',
          action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
            alert('Button activated');
          }
        }
      ]
    };
```

---

**2. factory/injector no anda =/**

renderizar el icono boton como componente

`app.components.js`

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ComponentFactoryResolver,
  ComponentRef,
  Injector
} from '@angular/core';

import { ButtonDownloadComponent } from './buttons/button-download/button-download.component';

...

  constructor(
    private http: Http,
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private injector: Injector
  ) { }
  factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(ButtonDownloadComponent);
  btnDownloadComponent = this.factory.create(this.injector);

  elTexto = this.btnDownloadComponent.location.nativeElement;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 20,
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      // Configure the buttons
      buttons: [
        'print',
        'excel',
        {
          text: this.elTexto,
          key: '1',
          action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
            alert('Button activated');
          }
        }
      ]
    };
```

`button-download.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { faDownload } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-button-download',
  template: `<fa-icon [icon]="faDownload"></fa-icon> Download`
})
export class ButtonDownloadComponent {
  faDownload = faDownload;
}
```

Agregar al module los import, declarations y entrycomponents

`app.module.ts`

```
...

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { ButtonDownloadComponent } from './buttons/button-download/button-download.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ...
    ButtonDownloadComponent
  ],
  ...
  entryComponents: [
    AppComponent,
    ButtonDownloadComponent
  ],
```

en teoría debería renderizar el asunto completo pero se queda a medias:

```
<button class="dt-button" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0">
  <span>
    <app-button-download>
      <fa-icon class="ng-fa-icon"></fa-icon> Download
    </app-button-download>
  </span>
</button>
```

---

**3 Custom CSS**

Definimos una clase CSS que simula ser fontawesome para poder poner `<i class="fe fe-download"></i> Download`, en el texto del botón.

Se puede o poner directamente en el app.component.css o inyectar un componente con su css.

Te pongo la segunda opción que es una variación de la propuesta **2**

sacamos el svgPathData, width y height de

```
./node_modules/@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faDownload.js
```

y armamos un svg en el css del componente

`button-download.component.css`

```
.fe:before {
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  content: " ";
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: -2px 0;
}
.fe-download:before {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="512" height="512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M216 0h80c13.3 0 24 10.7 24 24v168h87.7c17.8 0 26.7 21.5 14.1 34.1L269.7 378.3c-7.5 7.5-19.8 7.5-27.3 0L90.1 226.1c-12.6-12.6-3.7-34.1 14.1-34.1H192V24c0-13.3 10.7-24 24-24zm296 376v112c0 13.3-10.7 24-24 24H24c-13.3 0-24-10.7-24-24V376c0-13.3 10.7-24 24-24h146.7l49 49c20.1 20.1 52.5 20.1 72.6 0l49-49H488c13.3 0 24 10.7 24 24zm-124 88c0-11-9-20-20-20s-20 9-20 20 9 20 20 20 20-9 20-20zm64 0c0-11-9-20-20-20s-20 9-20 20 9 20 20 20 20-9 20-20z" /></svg>') !important;
}
```

Actualizamos el template del componente

`button-download-component.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-button-download',
  template: `<i class="fe fe-download"></i> Download`,
  styleUrls: ['./button-download.component.css']
})
export class ButtonDownloadComponent {}
```

La ventaja de esto último es que podes prescindir del fontawesome en el componente (y si limpias la app globalmente también)
Es básicamente hacer a mano el "Tree shaking" del final bundle.

**Nota**
Si alguien puede discernir por qué no funciona el método 2 (o si es un bug), estaría muy interesado en como resolverlo.
Me da la impresión de que está implícito en esta pregunta por eso no abro otra.

Comment: No lo habia pensado de esta manera, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4):

Deberías ponerlo de esta forma:

```
            text: '<i class="fab FA-ICONO-ICONO"></i>',
```

En la web de font awesome puedes elegir el icono que quieres mostrar y abajo te vendrá el código, tan solo tienes que sustituirlo por FA-ICONO-ICONO. Por ejemplo , para un boton con icono de PDF seria:

```
buttons: [
        //...
        {
            extend: 'pdf',
            text: '<i class="far fa-file-pdf"></i>',
        }
    ]
```

Si no utilizas AngularCLI, puedes probar esta otra forma:

```
<fa name="NOMBRE ICONO"></fa>
```

Un saludo

Comment: Bueno la primera forma es clara sino utilizara componentes, no se si miraste el [link](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome)? y lo segundo, si utilizo angular cli.

Answer (score 1):

Usas PHP?, por ejemplo este codigo es boton/icono y al darle click muestra un modal para modificar datos:

```html
<a href="" title="Modificar" class="text-success" data-target="#modificar_datos-<?php echo $f['iduser'] ?>" data-toggle="modal">
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
</a>
```

Y este es para eliminar el registro de la tabla

```html
<a href="#" data-href="./php/datos_eliminar.php?id=<?php echo $f['iduser']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete">
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash-o"></i></a>
```

Y aqui el modal de confirmar si deseas eliminar el registro

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">    
<div class="modal-header">
<h5 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Eliminar Registro</h5>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
</div>
    
<div class="modal-body">¿Desea eliminar este registro?</div>
     
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
<a class="btn btn-danger btn-ok">Eliminar</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Saludos

Comment: No uso php, trabajo con Angular

Answer (score 0):

Podrias cargar la/s fuente de font-awesome en tu css e introducir el caracter "a mano" (que es lo que hace basicamente el css de FA, cargar la fuente e introducir los caracteres con :before), pero seria poco eficiente porque cargarias muchos iconos que no vas a usar.
Si solo vas a usar unos pocos, quiza te interese más introducirlos como vectores svg y asi puedes cambiarlos al color y tamaño que necesites.
Aqui tienes una lista de los iconos de awesome en formato svg y png

https://github.com/encharm/Font-Awesome-SVG-PNG/tree/master/black

Comment: No quiero utilizar css por la misma razon, por eso utilizo https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome, pero no se cargarlos a traves de un script